# Is there a more elegant way to iterate objects methods and test all those conditions Java

Tags: java, syntax

I have the following code in Java and I want to minimize it or write it in a more concise way. Can you help me if this is feasible?

```
return( Objects.equals(obj1.getMeaning(), obj2.getMeaning())
        && Objects.equals(obj1.getModifies(), obj2.getModifies())
        && Objects.equals(obj1.getOriginalCommentString(), obj2.getOriginalCommentString())
        && Objects.equals(obj1.getReferences(), obj2.getReferences())
        && Objects.equals(obj1.getReturnDescription(), obj2.getReturnDescription())
        && Objects.equals(obj1.getReturnType(), obj2.getReturnType())
        && Objects.equals(obj1.getSuppressions(), obj2.getSuppressions())
        && Objects.equals(obj1.getTemplateTypeNames(), obj2.getTemplateTypeNames())
        && Objects.equals(obj1.getThisType(), obj2.getThisType())
        && Objects.equals(obj1.getThrownTypes(), obj2.getThrownTypes())
        && Objects.equals(obj1.getTypedefType(), obj2.getTypedefType())
        && Objects.equals(obj1.getType(), obj2.getType())
        && Objects.equals(obj1.getVersion(), obj2.getVersion())
        && Objects.equals(obj1.getVisibility(), obj2.getVisibility()))
```

Is it a good practice to give a list of the methods, as strings, and then create a map function to test them all one by one. I have read about reflection in Java but I am not that proficient.

Comment: Why not just implement equals() on your class?

Comment: override equals method with this logic

Comment: If you decide to implement `equals`, read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java

Comment: 14 fields is too many, try to decompose them into several classes

Comment: @AndrewTobilko why is 14 fields too many?

Comment: It is a matter of *opinion*.

Comment: Have you looked into the BeanComparator utility class?  https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanComparator.html

Comment: You may be able to make some use of [Apache's EqualsBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html)

Answer (score 4):

You could have a method like:

```
<T> boolean equals(T obj1, T obj2, Iterable<? extends Function<? super T, ?>> fns) {
  for (Function<? super T, ?> fn : fns) {
    if (!Objects.equals(fn.apply(obj1), fn.apply(obj2))) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

and then call it like:

```
return equals(obj1, obj2, Arrays.asList(Thing::getMeaning, Thing::getModifies));
```

etc.

Comment: This is growing on me.  Any way to turn the last parameter into a vararg, so you don't need the call to asList?